# How to add labels onto a form one under another?

Tags: c#, winforms

I made this program and it worked until it didn't... I was adding labels with text onto a form and setting label.Location = new Point(0, yPos); and then doing yPos += labelHeight;

It didn't make sense to me why at first my labels were fine and then I saw huge gaps between then, turns out yPos overflowed, so I can't use this method, is there some sort of container I can use to add labels one after another without setting label location? Also my labels can be of any height and there can be a lot of them.

I was adding these labels as controls of TabPage.

Comment: I can't see how you could reasonably have a form that's 2 Billion pixels high.  You should use a `Listbox` instead.

Comment: @DStanley i use scrollbar, that's why it fits, how can i add labels to listbox?

Comment: Or do you mean overflowed the _form_, not an integer overflow?

Comment: @DStanley, no the yPos integer overflowed, i was adding a lot of stuff to the form, and for the form I did this.AutoScroll = true, so whenever there was no more room in the window it adds a scrollbar at right.

Comment: You don't add labels to a listbox - you add strings.  Even with a scrollbar, 2 billion pixels is 1.2 Million "pages" at 2560X1600 resolution.  If you're overflowing that you are trying to show WAY too much data in one form.

Comment: @DStanley, well, idk, but listbox is not good for me, because I want to be able to have arbitrary height of the items, but it seems like listbox items are 1 liners, besides i want to add an event to the item with text, I click on it and it opens something in the web browser. I've already done it for labels, but if only there was a way to store them in some sort of container top to bottom..

Comment: sure, you could use a `DataGrid` but my point is if you are overflowing the `int` position there's no practical way anyone can consume that much data in one form.  Even if you could consume an entire screen in one second, it would take you over 15 days to consume all of the data. You need to reduce the amount of data that's shown DRAMATICALLY, either by filtering, paging, or both.

Comment: Huge gaps != overflow.  My crystal ball whispers that you forgot to tell us  that you set the form's AutoScroll property to *true*.  That requires you to adjust the Location by the amount the form is scrolled.  Add AutoScrollPosition.Y.

Comment: @HansPassant I didn't know that, thanks, what do I add that to?

Comment: @HansPassant, never mind, I figured it out, thanks a lot! you should add it as answer and ill accept.

Comment: Just post the solution yourself and mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out when you add things to a form, that has AutoScroll set to true, you should always do:

```
this.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(0,0);
```

This worked, thanks to Hans Passant.

Answer (score 0):

(Looking past the fact that you may be trying to add too many labels to begin with)

You might want to use TableLayoutPanel for adding multiple controls.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jpricket/2006/04/05/winforms-autolayout-basics-tablelayoutpanel/

I believe this is a method you can run on something like that

```
Table.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = "textHere", Anchor = ... etc};
```

That way you don't have to explicitly position everything within the panel, only the panel itself.

There are probably a few ways of doing what you're asking. A little bit of research on my part found that this method is generally the right way to go.

Unfortunately I am unable to test this at the moment, but it may put you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

You're ignoring the main problem which is that you are somehow overflowing the `yPos` value. So either your logic for setting the y position is flawed or you are displaying WAY too much data in one form.   My large 32-inch monitor runs at a resolution of 2,500 X 1,600.  The maximum value for `int` (and thus the maximum y value) is 2,147,483,647. Even a scrollable form that's over 1.3 Million "pages" of data at that resolution.  If I could process one "screen" of data *per second* it would take me 373 hours (15.5 days) to consume all of the labels in that form.

So the problem is *not* which control to use - it how to reduce the amount of data in one form to a manageable amount.  You need to look at filtering, searching, sorting, paging, etc. to get the amount of data to a manageable level.  Otherwise it's write-only memory.  You are displaying it but noe one is reasonably able to use it.

Comment: Actually you might be right, maybe I'm not even overflowing anything, because there isn't too much data, but then I don't understand why all of a sudden there's a lot of space between my labels. I just wrote "checked{}" around that code, and it didn't throw an exception, so I guess it's something else..

Comment: I would run it in the debugger and see if you can determine what the problem is. Does the space grow between each label?  Are you maybe adding the yPos back to itself _in addition_ to the label height?  (maybe `yPos += yPos + labelHeight`?)

Comment: Oh, no, that's all good, maybe it's because I'm doing a cross thread operation? I'm not very good with threads. If I was adding yPos to itself it wouldn't be ok in the beggining either. Because it's ok for some time but then it goes berzerk. Here's the code: http://ideone.com/EXQRHf .